# useradd: cannot open /etc/passwd

Tags: adduser, passwd, useradd, passwd-file

I am facing create a new user on my ubuntu 20.04 from GUI as well as terminal. I am getting following error:

```
sahadeb@HP-Elite-Book:~$ sudo adduser user1
Adding user `user1' ...
Adding new group `user1' (1005) ...
Adding new user `user1' (1001) with group `user1' ...
useradd: cannot open /etc/passwd
adduser: `/sbin/useradd -d /home/user1 -g user1 -s /bin/bash -u 1001 user1' returned error code 1. Exiting.
sahadeb@HP-Elite-Book:~$ sudo useradd user2
useradd: cannot open /etc/passwd
sahadeb@HP-Elite-Book:~$
```

---

```
sahadeb@HP-Elite-Book:~$ sudo ls -l /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2819 May 18 22:40 /etc/passwd

sahadeb@HP-Elite-Book:~$ sudo lsattr /etc/passwd
--------------e----- /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but damn, I could have sworn that the file was set immutable ...

Comment: Did you edit the file manually 2 days ago, maybe the format got corrupted?

Comment: Yes, I have edited this file manually from windows 10 due to some file system error I was unable to log in.

Comment: Please add this information to the question, too. Further readers might not read the comments.

Comment: Try `sudo dos2unix /etc/passwd` (you may need to install `dos2unix`). If that does not help, we need the contents of `/etc/passwd`. at least the part that you edited.

Comment: dos2unix work for me. I got the error and fixed it by deleteing the line.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
dos2unix works for me. I got the error and fixed it by deleteing the line.
sahadeb@HP-Elite-Book:~$ sudo dos2unix /etc/passwd
dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x00 found at line 48
dos2unix: Skipping binary file /etc/passwd.

Comment: Glad that I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You most likely introduced some error in the `passwd`'s syntax. You need to fix it.

Might be through editing from Windows you have introduced Windows line endings, try:

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
sudo dos2unix /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

Below action works for me

```
chattr -a /etc/shadow
```

I had the same problem and after checking the good one and bad one I found, so I take above action.

#### Bad

```
root@k8s1:/var/www/html/Piwigo/piwigo# lsattr /etc/shadow
-----a--------e----- /etc/shadow
```

#### Good

```
root@gallery:/var/www/html/Piwigo# lsattr /etc/passwd
--------------e------- /etc/passwd
```